# Using option id to change value of an html table text element with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I want to change the value of an html table text element using a toggle  and  dropdown. When the option is selected, the HTML table text element should change numbers. Here is the html and jQuery I have so far.

```
<select name="subject" id="subject">
    <option value="option1"  id="xTest">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2"  id="yTest">Option 2</option>
</select>

<table>
<tr>
<td id="testing">Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and the jQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#xTest").click(function(){
           ("#testing").text("change"); 
        });
    })
    $(document).ready(funtion() {
        $(#yTest).click (function(){
           ("#testing").text("change2"); 
        });
    })
</script>
```

When selecting either dropdown (#xTest or #yTest), the value of #testing isn't changing. Do I need to add an a href attribute to the html? This wouldn't make sense to me, however, because I am not adding a link.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the reason is a syntax error at `$(#yTest)`?

Answer (score 2):

Events are not supported cross browser on `<option>` elements. Instead use the change event on the `<select>` and use it's value to determine the text to display

```js
$("#subject").change(function() {
  const txt = 'change ' + (this.value === 'option1' ? 1 : 2)
  $("#testing").text(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="subject" id="subject">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="testing">Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Even though I closed the </select> tag, this still doesn't seem to work for me. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: What is it doing differently than in my demo here? I left out the document.ready as it isn't needed in this environment...you might need it for your app if code is above the select

Comment: Ahh, adding the document.ready solved the problem I was having. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Monitor `<select>` changes using jquery like this:

```
$('#subject').change(function () {

     const text = 'change ' + (this.value === 'option1' ? 1 : 2)
     $("#testing").text(text);


 });
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your code suggestion! When I tested it on my end, however, it still doesn't change the values in the table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure to include my script below the `<select>` and it'll work. If the script is above the `<select>` wrap the code above in `document.ready`